Minimal Smoothness Conditions for Gauss-Ostrogradsky Theorem
Recently I've learned about a stronger version of Gauss-Ostrogradsky theorem found thanks to the theorem of Sobolev spaces, that is:
Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set with $C^1$ boundary, and let $v \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} D^i v = \int_{\partial \Omega} Tv \, n_i dS 
\end{equation}
where $T$ is the trace operator.
Now, I know that the trace operator works even in Lipschitz domains, however it seems to me that it is really hard to find versions of the theorem where the requirement of smoothness of the boundary is weakened further that requiring the boundary to be piecewise $C^1$.
So the question is: if I define a set $\Omega$ to be normal if it is such that the trace operator is defined for all $v \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$, and the above equation holds for all such $v$, is there a (more or less) fine characterization of such sets?

I suggest you not call this “Gauss’ lemma”, and instead call it the Gauss(-Ostrogradsky) theorem, or simply the divergence theorem. In differential/Riemannian geometry, Gauss’ lemma refers to something completely different.

@peek-a-boo Thank you for the note, I'm editing the question

Here’s the divergence theorem/Green’s formula as stated in Grisvard, Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains, Theorem 1.5.3.1:

Theorem.
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ with Lipschitz boundary. Then, for every $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $v\in W^{1,q}(\Omega)$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}(D_iu)v\,dx+\int_{\Omega}u(D_iv)\,dx&=\int_{\partial\Omega}\gamma(u)\gamma(v)\,\nu_i\,d\sigma.
\end{align}
Here, $\gamma$ is the trace operator, and $\nu$ is the a.e-defined outward normal.

For the proof, he refers the reader to J. Necas Direct Methods in the Theory of Elliptic Equations, Chapter 3, Theorem 1.1.
Now, I don’t know about characterizations of sets for which such formulae hold, but the general idea is always to have sets nice enough for which $C^{\infty}_c(\overline{\Omega})$ is dense (and for which you have a nice enough unit normal $\nu$), and then argue the result by density in suitable function spaces.

Thank you very much for the answer, I found a version a little bit stronger than the one you mentioned in Necas' book, however hypothesis are really similar.

@LorenzoVanni which is it?

Theorem 1.1 in section 3.1.2 of Necas' book; hypothesis are the same except that Necas requires $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{n+1}{n}$ ($n$ is the dimension of the space) if $1\leq (p,q) < n$ or $q > 1$ if $p \geq n$ or $p > 1$ if $q \geq n$.

Oh that’s what you mean… yea Grisvard simplified it to the most common case, and I left out the general exponents as well because I’ve never had to use them. I thought you meant you found another source with even weaker hypotheses (which tbh wouldn’t surprise me); also if you really want to should look into some of the results in geometric measure theory.

Yeah I guess that maybe I've wrote that poorly. Thank you for the remark. Some time ago I've bought Federer's book about geometric measure theory, is that a good reference to learn the subject?

I’m not the right person to ask, but that is indeed one of the most commonly referenced books.
